# Search for a string at proximity with another string?

Tags: grep, find, search

Say I want to search for '123456789' and I want it to be near 'firstname'. Is there a way to do it?

I've 0 logic to do this. Maybe piping greps could work?

What kind of algorithm is best suited for this purpose?

**Input:**

```
search_string1='firstname' search_string2='123456789'
proximity_#_of_lines=10
```

**Output:**

Find `search_string1` and `search_string2` instance if they are 10 lines near each other. i.e if these two strings are 10 lines near each other then display it to a file.

Comment: It's still unclear what is the output. You can keep your sentence, but **provide the expected output**.

Comment: Do you want a yes/no answer, the line that contains `123456789` if it's within 10 lines of a line containing the substring `firstname`, or the other way around?  Is your data in some common format, like JSON, YAML, CSV, XML or other?

Comment: 1) There is a log file named application.log
2) When I do proximity search and such holds true:
a) either show me the file only in that case
b) let it be a way to highlight those search terms and view them
3) My files are general log files in .log file (normal text file).

Comment: When asked for clarifications, please edit your question to include the answers. For text-processing questions like this one, be sure to provide a (possibly anonymized) example of the log file you want to process, the search strings, and what the output should look like for your example input.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include statements of requirements for multiple matches, overlapping ranges, start/end on the same line, regexp metachars treatment, substrings treatment, etc. and sample input/output that covers your requirements so we can best help you. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more info on some of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard approach could be:

```
what_we_want='123456789'
context='firstname'
distance=10
grep -E -e "${context}" -C "${distance}" file_to_look_into | grep -E -e "${what_we_want}" -C "${distance}"
```

The first `grep` ensures that we only look `$distance` lines around `$context` matching lines. The 2nd then sees if it find `$what_we_want` in those `2*$distance+1` lines.

If you just want the matching line as a result, drop the `-C "${distance}"` from the 2nd `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings can only appear once each in your input then using any awk (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v str1='string1' -v str2='string2' -v prox=10 '
    index($0,str1) { nr1 = NR }
    index($0,str2) { nr2 = NR }
    nr1 && nr2 {
        delta = (nr1 > nr2 ? nr1 - nr2 : nr2 - nr1)
        exit ( delta > prox )
    }
' file

if (( $? == 0 )); then
    printf 'success\n'
else
    printf 'failure\n'
fi
```

Comment: They don't appear just once. Though!

Comment: Then edit your question to state that and any other unstated requirements and add concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your requirements so we have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Comment: I'll try to desensetize the data and make a log file.

Comment: Right, that is how people typically provide the "sample input" part of a [mcve], but remember to create and post the "expected output" part of it too. And make sure to cover the difficult rainy-day cases you can think of or you'll probably end up with a solution that only works for the sunny day cases.